# Xamarin.Forms - iOS app crash after start

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have xamarin forms application. On Android is everything OK. On iOS is possible to run app only if I use visual studio to deploy application to iPhone or when I use simulator. When I use TestFlight service then app crash on startup. Apple automation test fails too.
Part of crah log is here and full crash log is under this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aec6d88 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019addf1e8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019ad329b0 __abort + 112 (abort.c:147)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019ad32940 abort + 112 (abort.c:118)
4   Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101d9ee64 xamarin_printf + 25177700 (runtime.m:2472)
5   Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101c6475c mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 23889756 (exception.c:1299)
6   Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101bf95bc mono_handle_exception_internal + 23451068 (mini-exceptions.c:2783)
7   Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101bf9fb0 mono_resume_unwind + 23453616 (mini-exceptions.c:3532)
8   Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101bededc mono_arm_resume_unwind + 23404252 (exceptions-arm64.c:421)
9   Zaruky.iOS                      0x00000001006f5b38 llvm_resume_unwind_trampoline + 168
10  Zaruky.iOS                      0x00000001015762ec Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 16622316 (UIApplication.cs:0)
11  Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101c0b1bc mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 23523772 (mini-runtime.c:3165)
12  Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101cc6870 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 24291440 (object.c:3220)
13  Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101cccac8 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 24316616 (object.c:5284)
14  Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101be9774 mono_jit_exec + 23385972 (driver.c:1328)
15  Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000101da6900 xamarin_main + 25209088 (monotouch-main.m:0)
16  Zaruky.iOS                      0x0000000100607e4c main + 441932 (main.m:166)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019aed18f0 start + 4
```

I found some errors with Device log in visual studio:
[Visual studio - device log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFjhn.png)

[Full apple crash log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7lSrJ_J30yTuOaQX5_1TU_sXbpLe7Qk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The log you post does not help much. I would recommend you use some tools like AppCenter to get more detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create new project and move all code to this new project. Now is everything OK. But I don't know where the mistake was.

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).